# On Mac vim, how do I change the cursor to be a blinking block?

Tags: macos, vim, text-cursor

I'm using vim on Mac OS X.  I want to change the cursor to be a blinking block.  I attempted to follow the instructions here -- https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Change_cursor_shape_in_different_modes.  I created my ~/.vimrc file like so

```
localhost$ cat ~/.vimrc 
set pastetoggle=<F2>

let &t_SI.="\e[5 q" "SI = INSERT mode
let &t_SR.="\e[4 q" "SR = REPLACE mode
let &t_EI.="\e[1 q" "EI = NORMAL mode (ELSE)

"Cursor settings:

"  1 -> blinking block
"  2 -> solid block 
"  3 -> blinking underscore
"  4 -> solid underscore
"  5 -> blinking vertical bar
"  6 -> solid vertical bar

if &term =~ "xterm.*"
    let &t_ti = &t_ti . "\e[?2004h"
    let &t_te = "\e[?2004l" . &t_te
    function! XTermPasteBegin(ret)
        set pastetoggle=<Esc>[201~
        set paste
        return a:ret
    endfunction
    map <expr> <Esc>[200~ XTermPasteBegin("i")
    imap <expr> <Esc>[200~ XTermPasteBegin("")
    vmap <expr> <Esc>[200~ XTermPasteBegin("c")
    cmap <Esc>[200~ <nop>
    cmap <Esc>[201~ <nop>
endif
```

However, when I exit and restart my terminal, my cursor does not blink when I open a file using vim.  What else do I need to do to adjust my settings?

Answer (score 6):

I have the following in my `.vimrc` file. I do not remember where I got it from, but it might have been [this thread on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/ar1xer/help_ive_tried_to_change_my_cursor_shape_for_hours/). It works in both iTerm and Terminal, and with or without tmux:

```
let &t_EI = "\<Esc>[1 q"
let &t_SR = "\<Esc>[3 q"
let &t_SI = "\<Esc>[5 q"
```

This will give you a blinking block in normal mode, a blinking vertical bar in insert mode, and a blinking underscore in replace mode.

You will also have to enable blinking cursors in your terminal. For instance, in iTerm this is done in *Preferences > Profiles > Text*, where you enable *Blinking cursor*:

[image: Screenshot of iTerm preferences]